# Как настроить ЧПУ при многосайтовости?

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет !

Есть многосайтовость на разных доменах. Но на втором сайте не работает ЧПУ в компонентаъ news (хотя на первом сайте такой проблемы нет)

Содержание .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag allow_call_time_pass_reference 1
    php_flag session.use_trans_sid off

    #php_value display_errors 1

    #php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 day"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 day"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php7.c>
php_flag session.use_trans_sid on
php_value mbstring.func_overload 2
php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
</IfModule>
```

Содержание urlrewrite.php

```
<?php
$arUrlRewrite=array (
  'A' => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/catalog/garderobnye_sistemy/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => '',
    'PATH' => '/catalog/garderobnye_sistemy/index.php',
    'SORT' => 10,
  ),
  0 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/catalog/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/filter/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+/\\??.*$#',
    'RULE' => 'SECTION_CODE=$1',
    'ID' => '',
    'PATH' => '/catalog/section.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/bitrix/services/ymarket/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => '',
    'PATH' => '/bitrix/services/ymarket/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/acrit.exportpro/(.*)#',
    'RULE' => 'path=$1',
    'ID' => '',
    'PATH' => '/acrit.exportpro/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/personal/order/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:sale.personal.order',
    'PATH' => '/test/orderlist.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/personal/order/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:sale.personal.order',
    'PATH' => '/personal/order/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  32 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^#SITE_DIR#news/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/news/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  31 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/collections/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/collections/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  21 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/projects/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/projects/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  22 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/catalog/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:catalog',
    'PATH' => '/catalog/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  30 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/actions/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/actions/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  14 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/store/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:catalog.store',
    'PATH' => '/store/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  15 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^\\??(.*)#',
    'RULE' => '&$1',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:catalog.top',
    'PATH' => '/catalog/sale/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  18 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/rest/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => NULL,
    'PATH' => '/bitrix/services/rest/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

В urlrewrite.php на строке 53 лишний макрос #SITE_DIR#, его нужно убрать. Но он сюда добавляется из настроек компонента bitrix:news, поэтому нужно проверить чтобы его и там не было.